# LEFT JOIN in Codeigniter shows syntax error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, left-join

I want to select a table which holds all the issues a specific project id has. For that I am planning to do a LEFT JOIN and get the projects_id in Projects table to the column 'issues_projects_id' in issues table. Isn't it a `JOIN` that has to be used here?

```
    // $this->db->join('issues', 'issues.issues_projects_id = projects.projects_id', 'left');
   // $query1 = $this->db->get();
   $squery="SELECT * FROM projects LEFT JOIN issues ON issues.issues_projects_id=projects.projects_id";
    $query1= $this->db->query($squery);
    $query= $this->db->query($squery);
    return $query->result();
    return $query1->result();
```

The above code shows below error & displays no output.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `issues` ON `issues`.`issues_projects_id` = `projects`.`projects_id`' at line 2

SELECT * LEFT JOIN `issues` ON `issues`.`issues_projects_id` = `projects`.`projects_id`

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/projects/issue_tracker/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

**Projects** Table

| projects_id | projects_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

**Issues** Table

| issues_id | issues_description | issues_projects_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gfj | 1 |
| 2 | fghgj | 1 |

Comment: Since you are using the CI framework, take advantage of it with the correct CI syntax which you find described in detail here: [Selecting Data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) scroll to `$this->db->join();`, also check get() and from() functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `from statement`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `projects` --< here 
LEFT JOIN `issues` 
  ON `issues`.`issues_projects_id` = `projects`.`projects_id`
WHERE projects_id = ?
```

Comment: See the updated question. Not fectching the issues corresponding to the project id  still.

Comment: No error msg right now. But it fetches all the issues for any project, irrespective of the project id. I wanted to display only the specific issues of a project when we select a particular project.

Comment: @MG then your join condition might not be right, if not , this is what the query supposed to do

Comment: So,May i ask u what can i do to display the issues specific to a project. How should i modify the query?

Comment: @MG I would recommend accept the answer to this question and ask a new question with sample data and desired output , because that's a different question and needs a different asnwer

Comment: Please read the question correctly. I have mentioned my requirement in the first line of the problem statement.

Comment: @MG if you want  to show issue of a specific project , then you have to filter by projectid , which you can pass it as parameter . see updated answer

Comment: What shall I give in place of `?`

Comment: @MG the project id you want to show It's issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are self-joinin the table issue, doing that will no give you all the data that you seem to require.

Also a best practice is to NOT use `select *` but instead write all the required column name.

```
SELECT `Projects_id`, `projects_name`, `issues_id`, `issues_description`, `issues_projects_id`
from  `projects` 
LEFT JOIN `issues` ON `issues`.`issues_projects_id` = `projects`.`projects_id`
```